# Understanding proof of the Theorem 6.23 of the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds (about Riemannian covering map)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I am reading John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds, Second Edition, proof of Theorem 6.12 and some questions arises. ( I think that I'm unfamilier to Riemannian Geometry, please understanding ) :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am now trying to understand the underlined statements. A few of them seem possible, but I coudln't prove them rigorously until now.

Q.1. First (for the first underlined statement), as in the proof, he proves that the $\pi$ possesses the path-lifting property for 'geodesics'. And how can "path-lifting property for 'continuous' map" be proved?

Q.2. Let's go to the second underliend statement. I can't understand what he is saying exactly. If such a geodesic is lying in $U$, then it contradicts to the statement " all geodesics passing through $p$ and lying in $U$ are radial line segment" ? If so, why? What is the radial line segment?

Q.3. For the third underliend statement, why $d_{\tilde{g}}(\tilde{q}, \tilde{p}_\alpha) (= d_{\tilde{g}}(\tilde{q}, \tilde{\gamma}(r))) \le L_g(\tilde{\gamma})$ is true? I guess the reason as, "the $\tilde{\gamma}$ may not be the minimizing geodesic from $\tilde{q}$ to $\tilde{p}_{\alpha}$". Am I note correctly?

Q.4. Let's go to the fourth underlined statement. In fact, it seems that its proof can be achieved by direct check. But Can anyone give rough hint?

Thanks for reading. Can anyone help? I want to understand this stuff's more rigorously.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141782/discussion-on-question-by-plantation-understanding-proof-of-the-theorem-6-23-of).